# Parsing a string to a datetime does not return the correct time

Tags: java, android, datetime, hour, datetime-parsing

In Android...I am expecting 3:12 pm as time out put of the following code but I get 4:12 pm. Whats the correct way to parse this date time format.

```
String dt = "2018-09-02T19:12:00-0400";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dt);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Could it be that it's not using the same time zone you are?  Try formatting your date explicitly into a String, including timezone, and see what it says...

Comment: What is the desired output pattern?

Comment: And why do you expect `4:12 pm`, is your time zone `-07:00`?

Comment: I added dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone)); but still the output is one hour later.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Just checking, did you misunderstand the offset? `-0400` doesn’t mean that you should subtract 4 hours, but rather the opposite: the time is at offset -4 hours from UTC, in a way the 4 hours have already been subtracted. So 19:12:00-0400 is the same point in time as 23:12 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

### Time zone

It’s best to specify explicitly in which time zone you want your output:

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX");
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZoneId displayZone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pitcairn");

    String dt = "2018-09-02T19:12:00-0400";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dt, inputFormatter);
    String displayDateTime = dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(displayZone)
            .format(displayFormatter);
    System.out.println(displayDateTime);
```

This prints:

> September 2, 2018 at 3:12:00 PM PST

I have used Pacific/Pitcairn time zone in my code, but you know better which time zone you want.

I am also using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The date-time classes you are using, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are considered long outdated, and java.time is so much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your way of parsing your date string is correct and produces the correct `Date`.

When printing the `Date`, you are implicitly calling `toString`. The outdated `Date` class has a peculiar and confusing `toString` method: it grabs the JVM’s time zone setting and uses it for producing the string. So depending on your default time zone, you can get any hour of day in the output. So it seems your JVM’s time zone setting didn’t correspond to what you had expected.

Since you expected 3:12 PM from your input of 19:12:00-0400, I take it that you want a time zone that is at offset -08:00 from UTC in September. If for example your default time zone was America/Los_Angeles, the standard time of which is at -08:00, you would get `Sun Sep 02 16:12:00 PDT 2018` because summer time (daylight saving time) is in effect in California in September, so the offset is -07:00.

Relying on your JVM’s default time zone is always fragile since the setting may be changed at any time by other parts of your program or by other programs running in the same JVM.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.